# List of partition labels vs devices using dbus/udisks in bash

Tags: d-bus, udisks

I have a problem where using dbus and udisks seems to be the best approach.
So I invented a problem: create a table of labels and devices for each partition  "installed" ala:

```
  ""      /dev/sda1
  "ROOT"   /dev/sda2
  "BACKUP" /dev/sdb1
   ...
```

the thing is the more I think about how to approach this the more confused I get.
Can someone make some suggestions?

Comment: You have a problem and in order to solve it you invented a problem...? And what are "devices for each partition" supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is already provided by the command `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="10BE12331238FD148" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows7_OS" UUID="5CF2E12AD3438B42" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Lenovo_Recovery" UUID="C43211B2399007C54" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="4835b90f-4845-1234-8dcd-fbcf332338f8" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="av6WTb-CU69-4Ump-10dD-sudd-fTtC-Gf12AL" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root: UUID="75e0a75d-45d3-463c-bd87-9f7e123fd456" TYPE="ext4"
```

If you're trying to get that specific list of info you can get it using `blkid -o list` and some `awk` commands like so:

```
$ blkid -o list|tail -n +3|awk '{print "\""$3"\"", $1}'|sed 's/(not//'|column -t
"SYSTEM_DRV"       /dev/sda1
"Windows7_OS"      /dev/sda2
"Lenovo_Recovery"  /dev/sda3
"/boot"            /dev/sda5
""                 /dev/sda6
"/"                /dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root
"<swap>"           /dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_swap
"/home"            /dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home
```

See the [`blkid` man page for more details](http://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
udevadm info --export-db | sed  '
  /^E: DEVNAME=/{s///;h;d;}
  /^E:[^=]*LABEL=/!d
  G;s/[^=]*=\(.*\)\n/"\1" /'
```

The `udisks` equivalent being:

```
udisks --dump | sed '
  /^[[:blank:]]*device-file:[[:blank:]]*/{s///;h;d;}
  /^[[:blank:]]*label:.*[^[:blank:]]/!d
  G;s/[^:]*:[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)\n/"\1" /'
```

Comment: Does such a pattern make sense? `^[^=]*=.*`

Comment: That means: At the beginning of a line there can be zero or more non-"=", followed by a "=", followed by whatever. It seems strange to me to use a `^` then at all. OK, it makes a difference if more than one "=" appears in the line as you want "everything after the first '='".

Comment: Yes, the anchoring `^` is superfluous, since we know for sure that the pattern will match at the beginning of the line since the line above discards all the lines that wouldn't match.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$4 ~ /^sd[a-z][1-9][0-9]?/ {label="";
  cmd="blkid -o value -s LABEL /dev/" $4;
  cmd | getline label;
  printf "\"%s\": /dev/%s\n",label,$4;}' /proc/partitions
```

Comment: Note that contrary to `udisks`, you need read access to the devices for that (udev/udisks do call `blkid` to populate a database that everyone can query). Note that it returns the file system label. Partitions (like GPT ones) may also have a label.